# Angular factory returning only part of resource response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource, angular-providers

I have an Angular factory `DogePrice`:

```
.factory('DogePrice', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("https://chain.so/api/v2/get_info/DOGE");
}])
```

The typical api response is like this:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "name" : "Dogecoin",
    "acronym" : "DOGE",
    "network" : "DOGE",
    "symbol_htmlcode" : "&#208;",
    "url" : "http://www.dogecoin.com/",
    "mining_difficulty" : "18661.80200222",
    "unconfirmed_txs" : 7,
    "blocks" : 1119625,
    "price" : "0.00000046",
    "price_base" : "BTC",
    "price_update_time" : 1453938374,
    "hashrate" : "1289658619826"
  }
}
```

[Here is the JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/3nv7umbm/)

How can I create a factory that only returns the `data.price` field? I'd like to have a clean controller with only `$scope.price = DogePrice.get();` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do use promise return by `$resource` object. In that case you should use `promise` pattern to get data from the factory.

**Factory**

```
.factory('DogePrice', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
   var myResource = $resource("https://chain.so/api/v2/get_info/DOGE")
   var getData = function(){
      return myResource.get().$promise.then(function(response){
          //here you have control over response
          //you could return whatever you want from here
          //also you could manipulate response OR validate data
          return response.data;
      });
   } 
   return {
     getData: getData
   }
}])
```

**Controller**

```
DogePrice.getData().then(function(data){
   $scope.price = data;
});
```

Comment: may I know why downvote? please do add comment after downvote to point out whats wrong, and to imporve answer.. Thanks :)

Comment: I upvoted you. Still, my question is if the factory can be modified so that the controller contain only `$scope.price = DogePrice.get();` without the `then` callback. What I want is to have the final data, not the promise when the controller is executed.

Comment: @neptune may I know what problem you have with promise?

Comment: I have to handle data from multiple promises. I need to calculate the balance value on doge addresses based on price and I wouldn't do nested `promise.then`s.

Comment: @neptune you could take use `$q.all` for dealing with promise..whats the problem?